# Thread-safe object with databinding

Tags: c#, datatable, notifications, thread-safety

Background: My application receives asynchronous sensor data from a variety of IoT devices, displays it in several windows, and manages a physical system based on the data.  Data are not archived.  I am currently managing the data a C# dataset which contains several different datatables, each with just one row.  The datatable structures never change (add, remove rows, etc.) but individual values change constantly.  I am using a dataset/datatables architecture because its change notification plumbing is transparent; value updates are propagated throughout the application automatically and GUI databinding is easy.

Problem: Asynchronous updates to datatables are not thread-safe and eventually the dataset gets corrupted because multiple threads are making changes simultaneously.

Question: How can I consume asynchronous, dynamic data in a thread-safe manner and propagate changed values throughout my application... without complex plumbing?

Comment: "but individual values change constantly" Does that mean you never add/remove/replace  a`DataRow` but you modify a field of the row?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  For example, a DataTable might contain a single row with columns Current and Voltage.  The DataTable always has that one row but the values associated with Current and Voltage are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

In general, application development will be easier if only selected parts is run on background threads, with all other parts running on the UI thread.

I assume you need multiple threads for reading from the sensor data. So make sure all the threading stuff is managed inside the reader for the sensor. And when you get new data, do whatever you do to inform the rest of the application of the data on the UI thread.

If you want some more flexibility you could write an adapter that does this, or inject an optional synchronization context.

Answer (score 0):

Using mutable ADO.NET objects from multiple threads is only allowed if every write and read on every ADO.NET object than belongs to the same `DataSet` is `lock`-protected with the same locker object. The ADO.NET objects are highly interconnected. Changing a value in a `DataRow` of one `DataTable` might involve an internal read or write on the value of a `DataRow` in another `DataTable`, in case the two `DataTable`s have a relation with each other, which is registered in the `DataSet` that owns both of them.

I assume that you want to use the binding capabilities of the `DataTable`s, and bind UI components to them, so that the UI is updated automatically when the `DataTable` changes. This throws any solution that involves `lock`s out of the window. Your only real option is to prevent any thread other than the UI thread from interacting with your ADO.NET objects. You could funnel all updates to the UI thread by using the [`Control.BeginInvoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) method (or the [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke) if your app is WPF):

```
// At the location where you receive the sensor data.
form.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => dataRow.SetField(dataColumn, value));
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with ADO.NET.  Are your comments valid for C#.NET also?

Comment: @W9IP [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/) is the collective name for the tools that connect with databases and fetch data in .NET. It includes the `DataSet`/`DataTable`/`DataRow` classes.